# Custom nopCommerce Plugin Installs fine after building locally, but won't extract from .zip after uploading through interface

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I built a simple nopCommerce plugin and am able to successfully install it when building with Visual Studio and running nopCommerce locally. However, when I uninstall the plugin and try to use the upload interface to upload my plugin's .zip file, I get the following error:

> The archive should contain only one root plugin or theme directory. For example, Payments.PayPalDirect or DefaultClean. To upload multiple items, the archive should have the 'uploadedItems.json' file in the root.

Here is my plugin's JSON:

```
{
  "Group": "Misc",
  "FriendlyName": "Sort Manufacturers by Alphabet",
  "SystemName": "Misc.SortManufacturersByAlph",
  "Version": "1.01",
  "SupportedVersions": [ "4.30" ],
  "Author": "My Name",
  "DisplayOrder": 1,
  "FileName": "Nop.Plugin.Misc.SortManufacturersByAlph.dll",
  "Description": "Allows sorting of Manufacturers by alphabet. Go to Configuration->Settings->All Settings->SortManufacturersByAlph "
}
```

Here is the structure of my .zip directory:

[image]

I've noticed other plugins don't include the Nop.Core, Nop.Data, or Nop.Services DLLs in their build directories (could that be the issue?). I was able to remove these by adding the following to my .csproject file:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\Nop.Web.Framework.csproj" />
      <ClearPluginAssemblies Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

However this did not resolve the .zip upload issue.

To reiterate, the plugin builds successfully via Visual Studio and I am able to install it when the built files are in the Presentation/Plugins folder, it's just the .zip upload installation method that isn't working.

Comment: Not sure if you're trying to make zip works. You have to upload plugin's folder containing all the required dlls. If you can share your code on a public repo I can dig more into it. Also, nop 4.30 is not officially released yet, hence, would be better if you try with the source code of 4.20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I think.

I'm not sure what the problem was but it seemed to be with the way my Mac was zipping the folder.

I used this tool https://freetoolonline.com/zip-file.html to upload my built project and zip it that way. I was able to successfully install the plugin from this zip.

Not entirely sure what the issue was, but hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I face a similar issue on windows too. When I use the "send to compressed" feature of windows and tried to upload the plugin, I was treated with the same error message. I used 7zip to compress and upload and it worked fine. I suspect it was the compression mechanism of windows that generated the structure that was incompatible with the way NopCommerce implemented the feature. I hope this helps someone who is facing a similar issue.